# why always rank is 1?

Tags: c++

I am testing a very basic MPI code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int size, rank;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  if(rank == 0)
    cout << "world size" << size << " my rank " << rank;
  else
    cout << rank << endl;
  MPI_Finalize(); 
  return 1;
}
```

This code prints:

```
world size1324 my rank                                                                                                                                                                                      
0
```

which is ok.

When I do change the code to the following:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
  int size, rank;
  MPI_Status status;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

  if(rank == 0)
    cout << "world size" << size << " my rank " << rank;
  if(rank =! 0)                                                                                                                                                                                           
    cout << rank << endl;
  MPI_Finalize();
  return 1;
}
```

Output is:

```
world size111                                                                                                                                                                                               
4
my rank 
01
```

I run the code with -np 4

Why, in the second approach, is rank always printed as 1?

Answer (score 1):

As you may or may not have noticed, `rank` is originally 0, and then being set to 1. Look closely at your output. If `rank` was 1, it wouldn't print out `01`. It's printing the first line `cout << "world size" << size << " my rank " << rank;` where `rank` is 0, then printing out the second line `cout << rank << endl;` where `rank` is 1.

The issue here is with this line:

```
if(rank =! 0)
```

You aren't checking if `rank` is not `0`, you are setting `rank` to `!0`. It's effectively being treated as an assignment of booleans, and the opposite of 0 (false) is 1 (true). The `if` then evaluates the result of that assignment. So the line is essentially the same as:

```
rank = !0; // ie. set rank = 1
if (rank)  // 1 is true
```

What you should have is:

```
if (rank != 0)
```